# How to Extract QueryString Value from ShellTile NavigationUri

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, live-tile

I am creating my QueryString as follows when pinning a ShellTile to the start screen

```
var title = DateTime.Now.ToString();
string tileParameter = "uri=Title_" + title;

ShellTile Tile = CheckIfTileExist(tileParameter);  // Check if Tile's title has been used             
if (Tile == null)
{
    ...

    ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?" + "uri=Title_" + title, UriKind.Relative), LiveTile);  //pass the tile parameter as the QueryString
}
```

And my `CheckIfTileExists` method

```
private ShellTile CheckIfTileExist(string tileUri)
{
    ShellTile shellTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(tile => tile.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains(tileUri));
    return shellTile;
}
```

Everything works correctly in this. My issue is that when updating the tile's `Background` down the road I need to check to see if that particular tile is pinned already. I may have more than one ShellTile, and so I will need to update all of the Backgrounds accordingly. In the following code I was attempting to do this with a `foreach` statement, but since the `CheckIfTileExists` method only returns the `FirstOrDefault` I am only ever updating the first tile that was pinned, even though my `foreach` statement goes through every tile.

```
string tileParameter = "uri=Title_";

foreach (var _tile in ShellTile.ActiveTiles)
{                    
    ShellTile Tile = CheckIfTileExist(tileParameter);  // Check if Tile's title has been used             
    if (Tile != null)
    {
        ... update Background color
    }
}
```

How can I fix my loop so that it may go through every tile that is pinned and update? My idea was to extract the QueryString value, the `title` string value that was generated upon tile creation, and use this for `tileParameter` in the `CheckIfTileExists` method when updating. How could this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use `Where` instead of `FirstOrDefault` -- that should return all the matches:

```
string tileParameter = "uri=Title_";

foreach (var _tile in ShellTile.ActiveTiles
    .Where(tile => tile.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains(tileParameter))
{                    
    ... update Background color
}
```

Comment: Ok I will try this. Would you suggest that it would be better to create the `Where` check in its own method and call that similar to `CheckIfTileExists`?

Comment: @Matthew yes, I suppose that makes sense.